# Where Can We Ask "Is This Item/Spell/Ability Fair" Questions?

Tags: discussion

So I wanted to ask about whether a homebrew item is fair or overpowered, or even underpowered. However, I'm not entirely sure if those sorts of questions fit the guidelines of the site, so I chose not to post it.

What would be the best place to send someone to get that kind of question answered? Do we have any standard "go to site XYZ.com"?

Comment: You may find [this search](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=homebrew+balance+is%3Aquestion+closed%3A0) interesting.

Comment: @Miniman that's helped a bunch, thanks!

Comment: If you *do* wind up with a question that the Stack Exchange isn't built to handle, we have [some suggestions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/4398) for other sites that may be able to help, including our own [chat].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These types of question are difficult to phrase in a way that fits with this site, but it is not impossible as far as I am concerned. The key is being able to define 'fair', 'overpowered' or 'underpowered' clearly enough so that the question is very specific and there can be a definite 'correct' answer.

Comment: perhaps these questions are so out-of-scope as I thought, provided they're asked correcrtly! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Our site has guidance for how to ask balance questions. [What are the standards for balance questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4976/what-are-the-standards-for-balance-questions)
Also consider https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/22190/140 on the main site about how we define "Overpowered."

You can ask item balance questions here as long as you're careful to do it with quality guidelines in mind and ask for Good Subjective answers.  Don't just toss out an item and say "is it balanced." And hypothetical questions don't work well, maybe get some actual play in and have a real problem first.

And don't ask "fair," that's opinion bait.  "Balanced" is OK and "analysis of a specific aspect of it" even better.